# How can i get file_path of telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have a telegram bot webhook message like

```
{  
   "update_id":236420475,
   "message":{  
      "message_id":26577,
      "from":{  
         "id":xxxxxxxx,
         "first_name":"DB",
         "last_name":"Ks",
         "username":"xxxxxxxx"
      },
      "chat":{  
         "id":193044649,
         "first_name":"DB",
         "last_name":"Ks",
         "username":"xxxxxxxx",
         "type":"private"
      },
      "date":1493266832,
      "voice":{  
         "duration":2,
         "mime_type":"audio/ogg",
         "file_id":"AwADBQADBAADQKMIVC978KStO6ZhAg",
         "file_size":7532
      }
   }
}
```

From the [telegram bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file) there is a **file_path** specified for downloading the file. How can i get the **file_path** or any API for getting **file_path** by using **file_id**?

Comment: why you need file path? for what?

Comment: @anatol For downloading the audio file. I need to convert it for a text message.

Answer (score 9):

You can download a file in 2 steps:

1. call `getFile()` , in response you will be given a response as **Alexey Shablowski** has shown above where a `file_path` is returned with the response value
2. use this file path to call their file-downloading endpoint.

Ex. let's say, your bot **auth token**: `1234:abcd` and **file_id**: '`xyz890`'

*`getFile request:`*

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot1234:abcd/getFile?file_id=xyz890
```

**response:**

```
   {
      "ok": true,
      "result": 
        {
           "file_id": "xyz890",
           "file_size": 911,
           "file_path": "photos/file_name.jpg" 
         }
    }
```

Now get the `file_path` string value and construct your full downloadable link:

```
https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1234:abcd/photos/file_name.jpg
```

[API detail](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile)

Answer (score 2):

You should try to do that by [getFile](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile) method, which returnes a [File](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file) object. Just get *file_path* field from *File* and use it.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

request:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getFile?file_id=<file_id>
```

response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "file_id": "---",
    "file_size": 999,
    "file_path": "photos/file_59.jpg" <<--- file_path
  }
}
```