# Java Telegram Bot - How to get links to photos?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I send photos to the group

```
    public void executeImages() {

            InputMediaPhoto photo1 = new InputMediaPhoto();
            photo1.setMedia(new File("image.jpg"), "image.jpg");
            photo1.setCaption("Hello World");

            InputMediaPhoto photo2 = new InputMediaPhoto();
            photo2.setMedia(new File("image2.jpg"), "image2.jpg");
            
            // ......... And 8 more photos


            List<InputMedia> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();
            mediaItems.add(photo1);
            mediaItems.add(photo2);

            SendMediaGroup sendMediaGroup = new SendMediaGroup();
            sendMediaGroup.setChatId("1234");
            sendMediaGroup.setMedias(mediaItems);

            Message response = execute(sendMediaGroup);
            System.out.println(response);

    }
```

after which I receive a response

```
    ......
    "photo="[
       PhotoSize(fileId=AgACAgIAAx0EdU4tbQACArplMYIf1aguPWCCTyJtJdyDtv22SwACCdIxG8qriUmXo4IzUpGK7wEAAwIAA3MAAzAE,
       fileUniqueId=AQADCdIxG8qriUl4,
       width=90,
       height=90,
       fileSize=2673,
       "filePath=null)",
       PhotoSize(fileId=AgACAgIAAx0EdU4tbQACArplMYIf1aguPWCCTyJtJdyDtv22SwACCdIxG8qriUmXo4IzUpGK7wEAAwIAA20AAzAE,
       fileUniqueId=AQADCdIxG8qriUly,
       width=225,
       height=225,
       fileSize=14378,
       "filePath=null)"
    ]
    ......
```

Please tell me how can I use this answer to get all the links to the photos?

I tried using this method, [How can i get file_path of telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649537/how-can-i-get-file-path-of-telegram-bot)  but it doesn't work.

```
    I use
    https://api.telegram.org/file/bot5882468685:AAH3QIsQt3849xI-yKMJ_MV7QcN8XK7e32Q/getFile?file_id=AgACAgIAAx0EdU4tbQACArplMYIf1aguPWCCTyJtJdyDtv22SwACCdIxG8qriUmXo4IzUpGK7wEAAwIAA3MAAzAE

    return
    {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}
```

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.

Comment: Not scary. This is temporary for the test. Thank you for your attention.